# Error while adding multiple tvp values to datatable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, table-valued-parameters

I try to add a list with multiple columns to MSSQL database using table valued parameters.

I get this error:

> 'Unable to cast object of type '...Models.OptionValue' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <...OptionValue> in OptionID
>   Column.  Expected type is Int32.' InnerException:
>   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   '...Models.OptionValue' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

Sql Tvp table:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[OptionValueList] AS TABLE(
    [OptionID] [int] NULL,
    [ValueID] [int] NULL
)
```

classes:

```
public class OptionValue 
{
        public int OptionID { get; set; }
        public int ValueID { get; set; }
}

 public class OptionListVM
 {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public List<OptionValue> OptionValueLst { get; set; }
 }
```

this is where I try to add the columns in order to pass the list to stored procedure:

```
    DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
    tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OptionID", typeof(int)));
    tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueID", typeof(int)));

    foreach (var x in o.OptionValueLst)               
        tvp.Rows.Add(x); -- error line
```

I implemented IConvertable interface but it doesn't work. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OptionID", typeof(int)));
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueID", typeof(int)));

foreach (<OptionValue>x in o.OptionValueLst) {
DataRow dr = tvp.NewRow();
dr("OptionID") = x.OptionID;
dr("ValueID") = x.ValueID; 
tvp.Rows.Add(dr); 
}
```